# C++ when i try get string, it always empty, lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, g++

I have object of class

```
class MenuItem {
public:
    void updateInputText(string text)
    {
        this->text += text;
    }

    string getText() const {
        return this->text;
    }

    void trigger(Event event)
    {
        switch (event) {
            case ENTER:
                this->onEnterAction();
                break;
        }
    }

    function<void(void)> onEnterAction;

private:
    Text text;
    void onEnter();
};
```

I create object and set event handler

```
MenuItem IP;
IP.onEnterAction = eventOnEnter;
// ENTER - element from enum
IP.trigger(ENTER);
```

Event handler:

```
function<void(void)> eventOnEnter = [&] () {
    auto selected = next(this->currentMenu.begin(), this->selected);
    selected->updateInputText("Hello");
};
```

And second object of MenuItem

```
MenuItem nextButton;
next.onEnterAction = [&] () {
    Log::write("IP: " + IP.getText());
};
// ENTER - element from enum
next.trigger(ENTER);
```

But IP.getText() always empty. What i do wrong?

All objects created in one scope (in one function)

Comment: there is no obvious problem in the code you posted, though you are not calling either of the two lambdas, so `text` is not modified in the code you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surt gave me a hint... Scope.

All MenuItems pushed to vector, and when i use this function

```
next.onEnterAction = [&] () {
    Log::write("IP: " + IP.getText());
};
```

I try to get text from empty variable, when i changed function to

```
next.onEnterAction = [&] () {
    auto selectedIP = std::next(currentMenu.begin(), 0);
    Log::write("IP: " + selectedIP.getText());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see something like this

```cpp
MenuItem nextButton;
next.onEnterAction = [&] () { // Should next be nextButton???
    Log::write("IP: " + IP.getText());
};
// ENTER - element from enum
next.trigger(ENTER);
```

I'm waiting for a disaster to occur. And if you had shown a fully working example you would have noted that your example code might have worked ... so what is the problem.

The main problem is that you capture everything by reference, but from your code I can't se if it should work, but I think not in a large system, the reason is that the captured values have gone out of scope.

```cpp
std::vector<MenuItem> CreateMenu() {
  std::vector<MenuItem> res;
  function<void(void)> eventOnEnter = [&] () {
    auto selected = next(this->currentMenu.begin(), this->selected);
    selected->updateInputText("Hello");
  };
  
  MenuItem IP;
  IP.onEnterAction = eventOnEnter;
  res.push_back(IP);
  

  MenuItem nextButton;
  nextButton.onEnterAction = [&] () {
    Log::write("IP: " + IP.getText());
  };
  res.push_back(nextButton);

  return res;
}

void Call() {
  auto buttons = CreateMenu();
  // what is captured at this point???  
  buttons.back().trigger(ENTER);
}
```

Most of the captured has now gone out of scope.